# If $(A \lor C) \implies B$ and $(C \implies (\lnot A \land B))$ both hold, is $B$ true?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

**Problem Statement**

> If the two implications $$D \equiv \left[\left(A \lor C\right) \implies B\right]$$ and $$E \equiv \left[C \implies \left(\lnot A \land B\right)\right]$$ both hold, is $B$ true?

**My Attempt**

Here is the truth table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & B & C & D & E & D \land E \\
\hline
T & T & T & T & F & F\\
T & T & F & T & T & T\\
T & F & T & F & F & F\\
T & F & F & F & T & F\\
F & T & T & T & T & T\\
F & T & F & T & T & T\\
F & F & T & F & F & F\\
F & F & F & T & T & T\\
\end{array}
$$

**Conclusion**

The last row is an instance of when $D$ and $E$ are both true, and yet $B$ is false.  This occurs when all of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are false.  Hence, the proposition does not hold, unless at least one of $A$, $B$ or $C$ is true.

**Question**

> > Is this conclusion valid?  If so, is there a way to shorten the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is fine. You can shorten the argument by stating it in a more informal fashion, but it’s essentially still just the truth table argument:

> Suppose that $B$ is false. Since $D$ is true, $A\lor C$ must be false, which means that $A$ and $C$ must both be false. But then the falsity of $C$ ensures that $E$ is true, even though $B$ is false, so we cannot conclude from the truth of $D$ and $E$ that $B$ must be true.

Comment: Blimey!  How come I was not able to think of that approach?  Your answer saves me a lot of characters!  Thanks.

Comment: @user11235813: You’re welcome.